# php email function

Tags: php, email, function

One recipient: someone@example.com

```
mail("someone@example.com", "Subject: $subject",
    $message, "From: $email" );
```

If I want two recipients, can I do this:

somone@example.com and tom@php.com

```
   mail("someone@example.com", "tom@php.com", "Subject: $subject", 
        $message, "From: $email" );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a comma-separated list of addresses as the first parameter:

```
mail("someone@example.com, tom@php.com", $subject, $message, $from);
```

In fact, you can use any format supported by [RFC2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822), including:

```
$to = "Someone <someone@example.com>, Tom <tom@php.com>";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $from);
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben James.
I have no idea what RFC2822 is, but I will be reading about it.

Answer (score 3):

Nope you can't do that. As per defined in PHP's manual, the `to` parameter can be:

> Receiver, or receivers of the mail.
>
> The formatting of this string must
>   comply with » RFC 2822. Some examples
>   are:
>
> ```
> * user@example.com
> * user@example.com, anotheruser@example.com
> * User <user@example.com>
> * User <user@example.com>, Another User <anotheruser@example.com>
> ```

which means:

```
mail("someone@example.com, tom@php.com", "Subject: $subject", 
    $message, "From: $email" );
```

would be more appropriate.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 2):

Multiple email addresses go in as a comma separated list:

```
mail("email1@domain.ext, email2@domain.ext" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need CSV (comma separated value) list of email addresses contained within a single string.

```
mail("someone@example.com, tom@php.com", $subject, $message, $email);
```

Along the same token you had a few minor mistakes with the function parameters.

Comment: Actually CSV is a fairly well defined standard that this does not comply with. For example, in CSV, the space after the comma would become part of the next field.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 mail("someone@example.com, tom@php.com", "Subject: $subject", 
        $message, "From: $email" );
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also do:

```
$to = array();
$to[] = 'someone@example.com';
$to[] = 'tom@php.com';

// do this, very simple, no looping, but will usually show all users who was emailed.
mail(implode(',',$to), $subject, $message, $from);

// or do this which will only show the user their own email in the to: field on the raw email text.
foreach($to as $_)
{
    mail($_, $subject, $message, $from);
}
```